# LoopBlinn Cubic Curve Rendering - Serpentine arteffect

Tags: opengl, shader, vector-graphics, bezier-curve

I am trying to implement the Loop-Blinn cubic curve in java using the following source codes [GPU-Curve-Rendering](https://github.com/azer89/GPU-Curve-Rendering) and [WebCore](https://opensource.apple.com/source/WebCore/WebCore-1298.39/platform/graphics/gpu/). Both of them are showing few arteffects and i cannot figure out why. Here are my source code:

```
public class CubicBezier {
public enum CurveType {
    UNKNOWN, SERPENTINE, LOOP, CUSP, QUADRATIC, LINE
};

private FloatArray klm;
public boolean drawAdditionalTri;
public Array<Vertex> tris;
public Array<Vertex> plainTris;
public final float M_EPS = .00001f;

public Vector2 start;
public Vector2 ctrl1;
public Vector2 ctrl2;
public Vector2 end;

boolean once = true;

public CubicBezier(Vector2 start, Vector2 ctrl1, Vector2 ctrl2, Vector2 end) {
    this.start = start;
    this.ctrl1 = ctrl1;
    this.ctrl2 = ctrl2;
    this.end = end;
    drawAdditionalTri = false;
    tris = new Array<Vertex>();
    plainTris = new Array<Vertex>();

    compute(start.x, start.y, ctrl1.x, ctrl1.y, ctrl2.x, ctrl2.y, end.x, end.y, -1);
}

public void compute() {
    tris.clear();
    plainTris.clear();
    drawAdditionalTri = false;
    compute(start.x, start.y, ctrl1.x, ctrl1.y, ctrl2.x, ctrl2.y, end.x, end.y, -1);
}

boolean flipSerpent = false;
public void compute(float x0, float y0, float x1, float y1, float x2, float y2, float x3, float y3,
        int recursiveType) {
    Float fd1 = new Float();
    Float fd2 = new Float();
    Float fd3 = new Float();
    CurveType curve_type = determineType(fd1, fd2, fd3);
    float d1 = fd1.value, d2 = fd2.value, d3 = fd3.value;
    System.out.println(curve_type);
    plainTris.clear();

    float OneThird = 1.0f / 3.0f;
    float TwoThirds = 2.0f / 3.0f;

    float t1;
    float ls;
    float lt;
    float ms;
    float mt;

    float ltMinusLs;
    float mtMinusMs;
    float lsMinusLt;
    float ql;
    float qm;

    // bool flip
    boolean flip = false;

    // artifact on loop
    int errorLoop = -1;
    float splitParam = 0;

    klm = new FloatArray(12);
    for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
        klm.add(0);
    }

    switch (curve_type) {
    case UNKNOWN:
        break;
    case SERPENTINE:
        t1 = (float) Math.sqrt(9.0f * d2 * d2 - 12 * d1 * d3);
        ls = 3.0f * d2 - t1;
        lt = 6.0f * d1;
        ms = 3.0f * d2 + t1;
        mt = lt;
        ltMinusLs = lt - ls;
        mtMinusMs = mt - ms;

        klm.set(0, ls * ms);
        klm.set(1, ls * ls * ls);
        klm.set(2, ms * ms * ms);

        klm.set(3, OneThird * (3.0f * ls * ms - ls * mt - lt * ms));
        klm.set(4, ls * ls * (ls - lt));
        klm.set(5, ms * ms * (ms - mt));

        klm.set(6, OneThird * (lt * (mt - 2.0f * ms) + ls * (3.0f * ms - 2.0f * mt)));
        klm.set(7, ltMinusLs * ltMinusLs * ls);
        klm.set(8, mtMinusMs * mtMinusMs * ms);

        klm.set(9, ltMinusLs * mtMinusMs);
        klm.set(10, -(ltMinusLs * ltMinusLs * ltMinusLs));
        klm.set(11, -(mtMinusMs * mtMinusMs * mtMinusMs));
        System.out.println("d1 " + d1);
        for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
            System.out.println(i+": "+klm.get(i));
        }
        if (d1 < 0.0f) {
            flip = true;
            flipSerpent = true;
        }
        break;
    case LOOP:
        t1 = (float) Math.sqrt(4.0f * d1 * d3 - 3.0f * d2 * d2);
        ls = d2 - t1;
        lt = 2.0f * d1;
        ms = d2 + t1;
        mt = lt;

        // Figure out whether there is a rendering artifact requiring
        // the curve to be subdivided by the caller.
        ql = ls / lt;
        qm = ms / mt;
        if (0.0f < ql && ql < 1.0f) {
            errorLoop = 1;
            splitParam = ql;
        }

        if (0.0f < qm && qm < 1.0f) {
            errorLoop = 2;
            splitParam = qm;
        }

        ltMinusLs = lt - ls;
        mtMinusMs = mt - ms;

        System.out.println(d1);

        klm.set(0, ls * ms);
        klm.set(1, ls * ls * ms);
        klm.set(2, ls * ms * ms);
        klm.set(3, OneThird * (-ls * mt - lt * ms + 3.0f * ls * ms));
        klm.set(4, -OneThird * ls * (ls * (mt - 3.0f * ms) + 2.0f * lt * ms));
        klm.set(5, -OneThird * ms * (ls * (2.0f * mt - 3.0f * ms) + lt * ms));
        klm.set(6, OneThird * (lt * (mt - 2.0f * ms) + ls * (3.0f * ms - 2.0f * mt)));
        klm.set(7, OneThird * (lt - ls) * (ls * (2.0f * mt - 3.0f * ms) + lt * ms));
        klm.set(8, OneThird * (mt - ms) * (ls * (mt - 3.0f * ms) + 2.0f * lt * ms));
        klm.set(9, ltMinusLs * mtMinusMs);
        klm.set(10, -(ltMinusLs * ltMinusLs) * mtMinusMs);
        klm.set(11, -ltMinusLs * mtMinusMs * mtMinusMs);

        if (recursiveType == -1)
            flip = ((d1 > 0.0f && klm.get(0) < 0.0f) || (d1 < 0.0f && klm.get(0) > 0.0f));
        break;

    case CUSP:
        ls = d3;
        lt = 3.0f * d2;
        lsMinusLt = ls - lt;
        klm.set(0, ls);
        klm.set(1, ls * ls * ls);
        klm.set(2, 1.0f);
        klm.set(3, ls - OneThird * lt);
        klm.set(4, ls * ls * lsMinusLt);
        klm.set(5, 1.0f);
        klm.set(6, ls - TwoThirds * lt);
        klm.set(7, lsMinusLt * lsMinusLt * ls);
        klm.set(8, 1.0f);
        klm.set(9, lsMinusLt);
        klm.set(10, lsMinusLt * lsMinusLt * lsMinusLt);
        klm.set(11, 1.0f);
        break;

    case QUADRATIC:
        klm.set(0, 0);
        klm.set(1, 0);
        klm.set(2, 0);
        klm.set(3, OneThird);
        klm.set(4, 0);
        klm.set(5, OneThird);
        klm.set(6, TwoThirds);
        klm.set(7, OneThird);
        klm.set(8, TwoThirds);
        klm.set(9, 1);
        klm.set(10, 1);
        klm.set(11, 1);
        if (d3 < 0)
            flip = true;
        break;
    case LINE:
        break;
    }

    if (errorLoop != -1 && recursiveType == -1) {
        System.out.println("error");
        float x01 = (x1 - x0) * splitParam + x0;
        float x12 = (x2 - x1) * splitParam + x1;
        float x23 = (x3 - x2) * splitParam + x2;
        float y01 = (y1 - y0) * splitParam + y0;
        float y12 = (y2 - y1) * splitParam + y1;
        float y23 = (y3 - y2) * splitParam + y2;

        float x012 = (x12 - x01) * splitParam + x01;
        float x123 = (x23 - x12) * splitParam + x12;
        float y012 = (y12 - y01) * splitParam + y01;
        float y123 = (y23 - y12) * splitParam + y12;

        float x0123 = (x123 - x012) * splitParam + x012;
        float y0123 = (y123 - y012) * splitParam + y012;

        drawAdditionalTri = true;
        plainTris.add(new Vertex(x0, y0));
        plainTris.add(new Vertex(x0123, y0123));
        plainTris.add(new Vertex(x3, y3));

        if (errorLoop == 1) // flip second
        {
            compute(start.x, start.y, x01, y01, x012, y012, x0123, y0123, 0);
            compute(x0123, y0123, x123, y123, x23, y23, end.x, end.y, 1);
        } else if (errorLoop == 2) // flip first
        {
            compute(start.x, start.y, x01, y01, x012, y012, x0123, y0123, 1);
            compute(x0123, y0123, x123, y123, x23, y23, end.x, end.y, 0);
        }

        return;
    } else if (errorLoop == -1 && recursiveType == -1) {
        drawAdditionalTri = false;
    }

    if (recursiveType == 1)
        flip = !flip;

    if (flip) {
        klm.set(0, -klm.get(0));
        klm.set(1, -klm.get(1));
        klm.set(3, -klm.get(3));
        klm.set(4, -klm.get(4));
        klm.set(6, -klm.get(6));
        klm.set(7, -klm.get(7));
        klm.set(9, -klm.get(9));
        klm.set(10, -klm.get(10));
    }

    Triangulation(x0, y0, x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3, klm.toArray());

}

public CurveType determineType(Float fd1, Float fd2, Float fd3) {
    float d1 = 0, d2 = 0, d3 = 0;
    Vector3 b0 = new Vector3(start.x, start.y, 1f);
    Vector3 b1 = new Vector3(ctrl1.x, ctrl1.y, 1f);
    Vector3 b2 = new Vector3(ctrl2.x, ctrl2.y, 1f);
    Vector3 b3 = new Vector3(end.x, end.y, 1f);

    float a1 = b0.dot(b3.cpy().crs(b2).cpy());
    float a2 = b1.dot(b0.cpy().crs(b3).cpy());
    float a3 = b2.dot(b1.cpy().crs(b0).cpy());

    d1 = a1 - 2 * a2 + 3 * a3;
    d2 = -a2 + 3 * a3;
    d3 = 3 * a3;

    Vector3 d = new Vector3(d1, d2, d3);
    d.nor();
    d1 = d.x;
    d2 = d.y;
    d3 = d.z;
    System.out.println("a1 "+ d1);
    fd1.value = d1;
    fd2.value = d2;
    fd3.value = d3;

    float D = 3.0f * d2 * d2 - 4.0f * d1 * d3;
    float disc = d1 * d1 * D;

    if(disc == 0) {
        if (d1 == 0 && d2 == 0) {
            if(d3 == 0)
                return CurveType.LINE;
        return CurveType.QUADRATIC;
        }
        if(d1 == 0)
            return CurveType.CUSP;
        if(D < 0)
            return CurveType.LOOP;
    }
    if (disc > 0)
        return CurveType.SERPENTINE;


    return CurveType.LOOP;
}

public void Triangulation(float x0, float y0, float x1, float y1, float x2, float y2, float x3, float y3, float[] klm) {

    Vertex[] vertices = new Vertex[4];
    vertices[0] = new Vertex(x0, y0, klm[0], klm[1], klm[2]);
    vertices[1] = new Vertex(x1, y1, klm[3], klm[4], klm[5]);
    vertices[2] = new Vertex(x2, y2, klm[6], klm[7], klm[8]);
    vertices[3] = new Vertex(x3, y3, klm[9], klm[10], klm[11]);


    for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < 4; ++j) {
            if (approxEqual(vertices[i].xy, vertices[j].xy)) {
                int indices[] = { 0, 0, 0 };
                int index = 0;
                for (int k = 0; k < 4; ++k)
                    if (k != j)
                        indices[index++] = k;

                tris.add(vertices[indices[0]]);
                tris.add(vertices[indices[1]]);
                tris.add(vertices[indices[2]]);

                return;
            }
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
        int indices[] = { 0, 0, 0 };
        int index = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < 4; ++j)
            if (i != j)
                indices[index++] = j;

        if (pointInTriangle(vertices[i].xy, vertices[indices[0]].xy, vertices[indices[1]].xy,
                vertices[indices[2]].xy)) {
            tris.add(vertices[indices[0 % 3]].print());
            tris.add(vertices[indices[(0 + 1) % 3]].print());
            tris.add(vertices[i].print());

            tris.add(vertices[indices[1 % 3]].print());
            tris.add(vertices[indices[(1 + 1) % 3]].print());
            tris.add(vertices[i].print());

            tris.add(vertices[indices[2 % 3]].print());
            tris.add(vertices[indices[(2 + 1) % 3]].print());
            tris.add(vertices[i].print());
            System.out.println("insude triangle");
            return;
        }
    }

    if (intersect(vertices[0].xy, vertices[2].xy, vertices[1].xy, vertices[3].xy)) {
        if ((vertices[2].xy.cpy().sub(vertices[0].xy)).len2() < (vertices[3].xy.cpy().sub(vertices[1].xy)).len2()) {
            tris.add(vertices[0]);
            tris.add(vertices[1]);
            tris.add(vertices[2]);

            tris.add(vertices[0]);
            tris.add(vertices[2]);
            tris.add(vertices[3]);
        } else {
            tris.add(vertices[0]);
            tris.add(vertices[1]);
            tris.add(vertices[3]);

            tris.add(vertices[1]);
            tris.add(vertices[2]);
            tris.add(vertices[3]);
        }
    }

    else if (intersect(vertices[0].xy, vertices[3].xy, vertices[1].xy, vertices[2].xy)) {
        if ((vertices[3].xy.cpy().sub(vertices[0].xy)).len2() < (vertices[2].xy.cpy().sub(vertices[1].xy)).len2()) {
            tris.add(vertices[0].print());
            tris.add(vertices[1].print());
            tris.add(vertices[3].print());

            System.out.println("true");
            tris.add(vertices[0].print());
            tris.add(vertices[3].print());
            tris.add(vertices[2].print());
        } else {
            tris.add(vertices[0].print());
            tris.add(vertices[1].print());
            tris.add(vertices[3].print());

            tris.add(vertices[2].print());
            tris.add(vertices[0].print());
            tris.add(vertices[3].print());
        }
    } else {
        if ((vertices[1].xy.cpy().sub(vertices[0].xy)).len2() < (vertices[3].xy.cpy().sub(vertices[2].xy)).len2()) {
            tris.add(vertices[0]);
            tris.add(vertices[2]);
            tris.add(vertices[1]);

            tris.add(vertices[0]);
            tris.add(vertices[1]);
            tris.add(vertices[3]);
        } else {
            tris.add(vertices[0]);
            tris.add(vertices[2]);
            tris.add(vertices[3]);

            tris.add(vertices[3]);
            tris.add(vertices[2]);
            tris.add(vertices[1]);
        }
    }

}

public boolean approxEqual(Vector2 v0, Vector2 v1) {
    return (v0.cpy().sub(v1)).len2() < M_EPS * M_EPS;
}

public boolean pointInTriangle(Vector2 point, Vector2 a, Vector2 b, Vector2 c) {
    float x0 = c.x - a.x;
    float y0 = c.y - a.y;
    float x1 = b.x - a.x;
    float y1 = b.y - a.y;
    float x2 = point.x - a.x;
    float y2 = point.y - a.y;

    float dot00 = x0 * x0 + y0 * y0;
    float dot01 = x0 * x1 + y0 * y1;
    float dot02 = x0 * x2 + y0 * y2;
    float dot11 = x1 * x1 + y1 * y1;
    float dot12 = x1 * x2 + y1 * y2;
    float denominator = dot00 * dot11 - dot01 * dot01;
    if (denominator == 0)
        return false;

    float inverseDenominator = 1.0f / denominator;
    float u = (dot11 * dot02 - dot01 * dot12) * inverseDenominator;
    float v = (dot00 * dot12 - dot01 * dot02) * inverseDenominator;

    return (u > 0.0f) && (v > 0.0f) && (u + v < 1.0f);
}

public int orientation(Vector2 p1, Vector2 p2, Vector2 p3) {
    float crossProduct = (p2.y - p1.y) * (p3.x - p2.x) - (p3.y - p2.y) * (p2.x - p1.x);
    return (crossProduct < 0.0f) ? -1 : ((crossProduct > 0.0f) ? 1 : 0);
}

public boolean intersect(Vector2 p1, Vector2 q1, Vector2 p2, Vector2 q2) {
    return (orientation(p1, q1, p2) != orientation(p1, q1, q2)
            && orientation(p2, q2, p1) != orientation(p2, q2, q1));

}
```

}

vertex shader:

```
attribute vec3 a_position;
attribute vec3 a_texCoord;
uniform mat4 u_projTrans;
varying vec3 tex;
void main() {
    tex = a_texCoord;
    gl_Position =  u_projTrans * vec4(a_position.xy, 0.0, 1.0);
}
```

fragment shader:

```
uniform vec4 u_color;
varying vec3 tex;

void main() {
    vec3 uv = tex;
    float val = pow(uv.x, 3) - uv.y * uv.z;

    vec4 mycol = vec4(u_color.xyz, 1.0);

    if(val < 0.0 )  mycol = vec4(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    gl_FragColor = mycol;
}
```

here are few screenshot of the problems:
[image][image]

They suppose to be like these
[image]
This is an executable [jar file](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1_kBPPsNSs6L_NURDYLm9Rxs2lAr5SWlE) of the application.

Can anyone tell me how to fix this issue? i'm pulling my hair for few weeks now.

Comment: What artifacts are you seeing? Those curves look reasonable to me.

Comment: uploaded images please check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

found the problem, it was the shader. I am using following shader, that works fine

```
// Cubic.fsh
uniform vec4 insideColor;
varying vec4 v_textCoord;

void main(void) {
    vec3 v_klm = v_textCoord.xyz;
    float t = v_klm.x * v_klm.x * v_klm.x - v_klm.y * v_klm.z;
    float alpha = clamp(sign(t), 0.0, 1.0);
    gl_FragColor = insideColor * alpha;
}
```

Comment: Please include the essential parts of the solution in the actual answer rather than just linking elsewhere.